# izip_longest with looping instead of fillvalue

Tags: python

Not sure how to look around for this, but from `itertools` the function [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) does this:

`izip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-')` --> `Ax By C- D-`

I was hoping an iterable library would have something to do this:

`izip_longest_better('ABCDE', 'xy')` --> `Ax By Cx Dy Ex`

Preferably for an arbitrary number of iterables, being used to generate millions of combinations.  I'll write my own, but I figured I'd ask, since I'm sure my own won't be very pythonic.

Awesome, It was the cycle that I hadn't tried.  I was also able to get something working by nesting for loops on arrays instead of iterators, but this is much better.  What I finally used was this to handle similar to izip"

EDIT:
Ended up with

```
def izip_longest_repeat(*args):
    if args:
        lists = sorted(args, key=len, reverse=True)
        result = list(itertools.izip(*([lists[0]] + [itertools.cycle(l) for l in lists[1:]])))
    else:
        result = [()]
    return result
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> a = 'ABCDE'
>>> b = 'xy'
>>> 
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue='-'))
[('A', 'x'), ('B', 'y'), ('C', '-'), ('D', '-'), ('E', '-')]
>>> list(itertools.izip(a, itertools.cycle(b)))
[('A', 'x'), ('B', 'y'), ('C', 'x'), ('D', 'y'), ('E', 'x')]
```

etc.  And there's the arbitrary-number-of-iterables variant (assuming that you don't want the first argument to cycle, and that you're not really interested in itertools.product):

```
>>> a = 'ABCDE'
>>> bs = ['xy', (1,2,3), ['apple']]
>>> it = itertools.izip(*([a] + [itertools.cycle(b) for b in bs]))
>>> list(it)
[('A', 'x', 1, 'apple'), ('B', 'y', 2, 'apple'), ('C', 'x', 3, 'apple'), 
('D', 'y', 1, 'apple'), ('E', 'x', 2, 'apple')]
```

Comment: Awesome, It was the cycle that I hadn't tried. I was also able to get something working by nesting for loops on arrays instead of iterators, but this is much better. What I finally used was this to handle similar to izip.  

`lists = sorted(args, key=len, reverse=True)`  

`result = list(itertools.izip(*([lists[0]] + [itertools.cycle(l) for l in lists[1:]])))`

Comment: very important while generating dictionary from a list that have headers in first some elements!

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3 you want to use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)
As `izip_longest` has been deprecated.

```
import itertools
list = list(itertools.zip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-'))
print(list) // --> Ax By C- D-
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on DSM's answer:
If you don't know which one of you lists will be the longest, be careful with `cycle`, as it's essentially an infinite loop.

You can use this:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, cycle
>>>
>>> a = "abcd"
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c = "WXYZK"
>>> things = a, b, c
>>> 
>>> longest = max(things, key=len)
>>> list(izip(*[x if x is longest else cycle(x) for x in things]))
[('a', 1, 'W'), ('b', 2, 'X'), ('c', 3, 'Y'), ('d', 1, 'Z'), ('a', 2, 'K')]
```